# Do you have to save?

Tags: dnd-5e, saving-throw

When players are asked to make a saving throw, can they just chose to not make the roll (and fail) or are they required to try?

Obviously when it comes to death saves they have to, but in a hypothetical situation where both passing and failing the save will have the same outcome e.g A dragons breath in your area and you have 1 hit point.

Is there anything (other than the DM) stopping players from just not trying to save?

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate since it has been asked before.